# How to force asp .net MVC decimal displays without leading zero at the end (using DisplayFormat)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My value in database is 17.5 but when asp .net MVC render it (decimal), it always shows 17.50. How can I remove the zero at the end using DisplayFormat attribute (I mean -> 17.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like this:

**0** - Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

**#** - Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}")]
```

Comment: Thank you Gabe, you save my hours :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Remove trailing zeros  in view**

**View Model**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:G29}")]
public decimal? Discount { get; set; }
```

**In View:**

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=> item.Discount)
```

Hope helps someone..